# jRuby: use oracle database

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jruby

I try to put this simple MRI script to work in jRuby but i get the error below.
I installed the same gem as in my MRI
I don't wanna use JDBC of Active Record, just make a simple connection and query, what should i do ?

```
C:\jruby-1.7.4\bin>jruby -S gem list --local
```

gives

```
..
ruby-oci8 (2.1.0 x86-mingw32)
..
```

the script

```
require 'oci8'

$conn = OCI8.new('test','test','dbcm.cm_121')

sql = %q{
  select * from table
 }

$conn.exec(sql).fetch_hash do |r|
  r.each {|key, value| puts "#{key} is #{value}"}
  puts ""
end

$conn.logoff
```

the error

```
C:\jruby-1.7.4\test>jruby fetch_sql.rb
LoadError: no such file to load -- oci8lib_jruby191
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054
  require at C:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
   (root) at C:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.0-x86-mingw32/lib/oci8.rb:43
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054
   (root) at C:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:1
   (root) at fetch_sql.rb:1
```

Comment: oci8 is the c library..: I would use a library that is based on the oracle jdbc driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it it is not possible, otherwise please let us know.
Here the shortest/simplest example i could produce using jdbc

```
require 'java'

#source: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/jruby-oracle11g-330825.html

java_import 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
java_import 'java.sql.DriverManager'

begin
  oradriver = OracleDriver.new
  DriverManager.registerDriver oradriver
  user = 'xxx'
  passwd = 'xxx'
  url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxx:9999:xxxx'
  conn = DriverManager.get_connection url, user, passwd
  select_sql = "select * from resources"
  select_stmt = conn.create_statement
  rset = select_stmt.execute_query select_sql
  while (rset.next)
    puts "    resource [#{rset.getInt(1)}, #{rset.getString(2)}]"
  end
rescue
  puts "Failed executing Oracle demo from JRuby ", $!, "\n"
ensure
  select_stmt.close
  conn.close_connection
end
```